# Unable to start zookeeper in windows 11

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I've downloaded kafka and extracted in C drive with the directory being C:\kafka
I've also added ZOOKEEPER_HOME=C:\kafka as a system variable and added C:\kafka\bin to the Path system variable.

However, whenever I run the command .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-starter.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties from the command prompt after entering C:\kafka, I get **'zookeeper-server-starter.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I've tried different variations of bin\windows\zookeeper-server-starter.bat config\zookeeper.properties but it is still not working.

Also, conf directory is not there but config directory is there, so I couldn't locate the .cfg file which many people have changed. The problem is very annoying.

Comment: You're mistyping the command. It's not starter. Just start. Also Kafka doesn't require that you start Zookeeper anymore